# Rails Ajax Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firefox

I have a Rails app that uses an `ajax` call to (right now) get a `JavaScript` alert message. It works in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox (all current versions). I can step through the code in Firebug and there are no errors raised, yet in the Console section, it lists nothing. Not even an error from the server; nothing. As if Firefox just forgot to do anything about it. Why would this not work?

Here is my code (in CoffeeScript):

```
jQuery ->
  $.ajax
    url: "advertisements/grab"
    method: "GET"
    dataType: "script"
```

Comment: Is there any difference on the server side?

I usually use link_to some_path, remote:true, id:"the_link" and $("#the_link).click() on the js

Comment: @NicolasMaloeuvre If I have a `remote: true` link, then that link works by itself. However, if I hijack the `click()` callback and call my `ajax` request inside there (and return false to prevent the link default), it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't try to hijack a remote: true link, except if you know well internals of jquery-ujs gem (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Comment: Then why did you suggest it? Either way, an `$.ajax` request isn't working and I don't use a link in my code.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to say that i don't like to call $().ajax({some custom params}) by myself, just keeping the "high-level logic" with $().click(). Maybe a JS guy could give a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Adblock Plus. Once I disabled it, then the Ajax was working correctly.